# javascript function onsubmit not working

Tags: javascript, php, submit

I am trying out [this tutorial](http://ahmeddirie.com/technology/web-development/salesforce-soap-api-and-php/comment-page-1/#comment-1338). I have created an index.php that contains a form with the following code. The problem is that the form doesnt get submitted at all. The alerts arent called. Nothing happening.

```
<?php
require_once ('/soapclient/inc_connection.php');
 function insert()
 // if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 //Describing the Leads object and printing the array
 $describe = $connection->describeSObjects(array('Lead'));
 print_r($describe);

 //Create New Lead
 $leadFirstName = "Ahmed";
 $leadLastName = "Dirie";
 $leadCompany = "Pick Yours Up";
 $leadEmail = "adirie@pickyoursup.com";

 //Creating the Lead Object
 $lead = new stdClass;
 $lead->type = 'Lead';
 $lead->fields = array(
      'FirstName' => $leadFirstName,
      'LastName' => $leadLastName,
      'Company' => $leadCompany,
      'Email' => $leadEmail
 );

 //Submitting the Lead to Salesforce
 $result = $connection->create(array($lead), 'Lead');
 }
?>
```

HTML:

```
 <h3>Sign up for an evaluation:</h3>

<span id="php_code"> </span>
 <form action="https://docs.google.com/..../formResponse"  method="POST" id="" target="_self" ><ol style="padding-left: 0">

        <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
 <input type="button" name="submit" value="Contact Us" id="ss"  onclick="return postToSql();"/>
 ....
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">

 function postToSql()
 {
  alert('1');

 alert("<?php insert(); ?>");
 //return false;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do...?

Comment: trying to post data to salesforce onsubmit. following a tutorial (link posted).

Comment: Check Console..Getting any error?

Comment: If you are using Firfox Browser then you must install Firebug plugin into the browser to look into the error in above mentioned term `console`

Comment: Error: postToSql() not defined. It is defined though....

Comment: @@Padyster Actually he can also use the "Inspect Element" feature.

Comment: Rt. now the "<script>" is at the bottom and so I guess the function is unreachable. If I move my "<script>" to the top of the page then the "<form>" doesnt render.

Comment: its working fine at my side, your all snippet are in one file?

Comment: I am using XAMPP btw, if that matters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the output value from your PHP function "insert()" causing a javascript error. So your javascript function seems to be undefined. Try changing your insert() function to this you will see the difference.

```
function insert()
{
    echo "something to alert";
}
```

And then,

```
function insert()
{
    echo 'something " to alert';
}
```

To solve this problem be sure that the output value of your function does not cause errors because of Quotation(") and Apostrophe(') Marks.

If you need to use Javascript and PHP combined like this, i suggest using Ajax.

Comment: Okay you are rt. But how could the output of my php function be affecting it. I am just trying to SEND data to salesforce. What do you suggest I should do? Other than ajax I mean...

Comment: You have `print_r($describe);` in your code, this output may be causing the error. Try removing it.

Comment: No thats not it. Its the first and the last line in my PHP

Comment: You need to check the page source from your browser. It will show the exact output in the `alert()`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function describeSObjects() on a non-object

Comment: Fatal Error causes your script to stop and not output the rest of the page and it leads to a Javascript error. You must correct the PHP error and check the source code again until it's valid.